# Find maximum value of red, green and blue arrays from an image using php when at least one of them doesn't have values

Tags: php, image, image-processing, rgb

I'm working on a project that involves extracting Red, green and blue values from an image and finding the maximum value of red values, green values and blue values.
When I upload an image that doesn't contain red values I got this error message: Undefined offset. The same message appears if image doesn't contain green or blue values.
I used empty() to check if array is empty but it didn't help.

my code:

```
for($j1=0;$j1<=$red_count;$j1++){
    if (empty($reds)){
        $reds[$j1]=0;
    }
    if ($reds[$j1]>=$red_max){
        $red_max = $reds[$j1];
    }   
}

for($j2=0;$j2<=$blue_count;$j2++){
    if (empty($blues)){
        $blues[$j2]=0;
    }
    if ($blues[$j2]>=$blue_max){
        $blue_max = $blues[$j2];
    }
}

for($j3=0;$j3<=$green_count;$j3++){
    if (empty($greens)){
        $greens[$j3]=0;
    }
    if ($greens[$j3]>=$green_max){
        $green_max = $greens[$j3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined offset refers not to empty value but to non-set one (key). try `isset()`

Comment: or jsut  check that $reds>0 do same for green and blues

Comment: $reds = array_fill(0, 256, 0);
$blues = array_fill(0, 256, 0);
$greens = array_fill(0, 256, 0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just look at one color. The problem is your for-loop. Because it is run once, even if $reds is empty. (And it's run on time to often.) Why not use foreach?

```
$red_max = 0; //initialize
foreach ($reds as $value) {
    if ($value > $red_max) { $red_max = $value; }
}
```

I guess you can apply this for the different colors.

Answer (score 1):

The function [max](http://php.net/max) works with arrays as well.

```
if(sizeof($reds) > 0){
$red_max = max($reds);
}
if(sizeof($blues) > 0){
$blue_max = max($blues);
}
if(sizeof($greens) > 0){
$green_max = max($greens);
}
```